# Get data from mysql database after login in combobox c#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have tried alot of things and also did research here on stackoverflow but can`t find anything that works for me.

I want to fill my Combobox with data that is saved in my database, the data need to be collected after I am loged in but the box stays empty..

Here is the code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Lys2FHLV

Hope someone can help me with this beceause I am trying to fix this for like 4 days now..

(btw. I just started with c# and I am not a professional..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a break point after you get the values for your combo box, check till there if you have the right values or an empty list. If the list is empty you will know that the problem is in the code before getting the list. Learn to debug your code by following it and understanding what is happening.